# What beracha do sefardim make on pizza?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern

What beracha do sefardim make on pizza? Does the amount of slices eaten make a difference?

Comment: Ani lo Yodeya for sure but you are asking a good question. From my observation, some Ashkenaz made pita bread contain fruit juice. I don't recall seeing juice listed as an ingredient in Sephardic made pita bread. Perhaps the same would apply to pizza dough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Rav Bentzion Abba Shaul 2:perek 12:5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19979&st=&pgnum=116) that if the dough is plain(not mixed with milk or oil) and tomato sauce and cheese is placed **ontop** not inside the  dough it is hamotzei. See footnotes as well. It also seems that the amount of slices make no difference since it is considered pas.